# Spring & Hibernate : generate dataBase using Spring Configuration

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to use SchemaExport in my app to create the DB schema in my applicatione. I'm using Spring configuration file to create  SessionFactory bean, but o dont know how to use SessionFactory bean to generate my Database.

**spring.xml :**

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />  

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
        </beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>        
        <mapping class="com.test.model.Personne" />

    </session-factory>         
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto configuration property to make Hibernate generate the tables according to the Hibernate mappings.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) in the "Miscellaneous Properties" section.